# Checking encrypted Azure SQL Server traffic

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-network

I have a client which makes connection to a Azure SQL Server. In the connection string I have added `Encrypt=True` to make sure that the data between SQL Server and the client is encrypted.

Now I want to check if this is really the case and that I (and everyone else) cannot see SQL queries.What is the best way to check this? I can use a sniffer like Wireshark to check the traffic on port 1433 (the SQL port), but is this the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

It is true that all connections to SQL Azure are encrypted – whether you use the `Encrypt=True` string or not. It will force the connection to encrypt even if you don’t- as connection settings cannot reduce the level of security. However, you do want to use that string, for a couple of reasons.

Whenever you include the `Encrypt=True` string, the connection will require that your client validate the Certificate that SQL Azure presents, to ensure that key is the one used by Microsoft. If you don’t include that string, it’s possible – not probable, but possible – that someone could set up a false DNS to cause your certificate to be validated elsewhere. More likely, the certificate will not be validated. And if the certificate cannot be validated, the connection attempt fails. For more information please refer to [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckwoody/2012/03/06/sql-azure-requiring-encrypttrue/) and [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254500(v=vs.110).aspx).

So, when you use tool to capture the packet, you all get encrypted packets.No one could see your queries.

Comment: Thank you for this very concise answer!